# Habit maker for kids

Tags: android, productivity, web

I observed that my daughter (4 years old) is interested to cross days in calendar as she is waiting for trade fair. She is also interested in marking habits in loop habit android application for daily prayer.

I'm wondering if there is some habit maker application (android or web or installer) designed specially for kids.

- Use of colors what kids like,
- Use illustrations,
- Instead of showing success graph, it shows map / path to get the trophy,
- different image for each routine task

Comment: Not using any such, but while waiting for good recommendations, maybe [this page](https://www.appbrain.com/app/kids-learn-good-habits/com.riverstudio.goodhabbits) is a good starter. Also scroll down and check related apps. Note: Appbrain is just another front-end to Playstore, so apps listed here are available there ;)

Comment: "Goal Meter" is a good option which covers at least the second point.